# What should be passed as the first parameter validator.addClassRules

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a text field :

```
<input type="text" id="abc" name="abc" class="form-control input-xs inline"/>
```

I want to apply a jquery validation using class rule on this text field

My question is what value I should pass as first parameter to addClassRules so that validation is applied on the text field

```
$.validator.addClassRules(<nameofclass>,{
        number: true,
        positiveNumber: true
        mymethod: true
    });
```

Comment: `<nameofclass>` means "name of class"... what are you asking exactly?

Comment: Sorry, for not explaining my question clearly. When there is only 1 class in the HTML and I pass that class in addClassRules then it works. But I have 3 classes in the HTML and when I pass all the classes in the addClassRules it does not work. So, I want to know in this case what value should be passed.

Comment: There is no point in doing that.  You simply use this method to assign the compound rule to ONE class.  Then you would add that class on the field where you want the rule(s) assigned.  See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *"My question is what value I should pass as first parameter to `addClassRules` so that validation is applied on the text field"*

[As per docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/), the first parameter is simply the name of the class you want to use.

```
$.validator.addClassRules("ClassName", {
    number: true,
    positiveNumber: true, // <- you also forgot this comma
    mymethod: true
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" id="abc" name="abc" class="ClassName form-control input-xs inline"/>
```